# What determines the reproduction ratio when lens stacking for macro shots?

Tags: lens, macro

When stacking one lens on another for macro shots (often a normal or wide angle on a telephoto ), what determines the maximum reproduction ratio that the combination can do?

Answer (score 4):

$$ M = {F_p \over F_r} $$

where

- \$M\$ = magnification
- \$F_p\$ = Focal length of the prime lens
- \$F_r\$ = Focal length of the reversed lens

*Source: Peter Forsell's great page about [Math for macro photographers](https://web.archive.org/web/20120211060836/http://www.peterforsell.com/macro.html#Magnification_of_a_reversed_lens).*