# How can I calculate magnification ratio I get by reversing a lens?

Tags: macro, reverse-mount, magnification

I am looking for a way to **mathematically determine the maximum magnification ratio** that is possible/practical to achieve by reverse mounting a non-macro lens, *prior to purchasing the lens*.

---

See related questions:

- [How can I estimate the reproduction ratio of an unknown macro setup?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13228/how-can-i-estimate-the-reproduction-ratio-of-an-unknown-macro-setup)
- [What does the magnification ratio number mean on a macro lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/what-does-the-magnification-ratio-number-mean-on-a-macro-lens)
- [What determines the reproduction ratio when lens stacking for macro shots?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18741/what-determines-the-reproduction-ratio-when-lens-stacking-for-macro-shots)
- [How can I calculate the change an extension tube makes to the maximum magnfication of a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9888/how-can-i-calculate-the-change-an-extension-tube-makes-to-the-maximum-magnficati)
- [How can I calculate what the effect of an extension tube will be?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/how-can-i-calculate-what-the-effect-of-an-extension-tube-will-be)

Comment: Wouldn't this require some type of value to be assigned to the reversing hardware? I don't recall seeing anything like that on any that I own.

Comment: If the reversing hardware contains no optical elements, shouldn't it have little to no effect on anything other than the focus plane?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magnification will indeed depend on your reversing hardware. The more distance you put between the lens and the body, the higher the magnification. The exact formula is:

$$ \text{magnification} = \frac{\text{lens-to-sensor distance}}{\text{focal length}} - 1$$

The problem is that the distance from the lens to the sensor has to be measured from the relevant
[principal plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_plane) of the lens, i.e. the object side principal plane, which becomes image-side once the lens is reversed. Then, to compute the magnification, you need to know the position of this plane inside the lens. Alas, I have never seen this information published for current lenses. You may be able to compute this position yourself... provided you have the complete formula of the lens! Finding the necessary data may be harder that finding someone you could borrow the lens from to do an actual test.

As for the question of what is practical... assuming you can achieve unlimited magnification (bellows, etc...) you will likely be limited by the resolution getting bad at too high magnifications. You can expect the MTF50 of the lens to be roughly divided by the magnification. Then the maximum *practical* magnification will be:

$$ \text{max magnification} = \frac{\text{lens resolution}}{\text{required resoltion}} $$

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you cannot determine that magnification ratio mathematically.

Peter Forsell's great [Math for macro photographers](https://web.archive.org/web/20121106064353/http://www.peterforsell.com/macro.html) page contains lots of macro magnification ratio calculations for different scenarios, but in the [section about the reversed lens](https://web.archive.org/web/20120211060836/http://www.peterforsell.com/macro.html#Magnification_of_a_reversed_lens), he claims the following:

> We cannot directly calculate the zero extension magnification (Zm) of
> the lens we wish to mount in a reverse position. Instead we have to
> take a test photograph of a ruler to determine this value or find the
> information in the lens manual.